# Page load first time:Page index in gridView not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two gridView: `grvHeadline` and `gdvNotification`, `gdvNotification` is load data by selected item of grvHeadline .

When page load: data of `gdvNotification` is load by first item of `grvHeadline`.

My problem is:

The page load is first: if `gdvNotification` has paging (1,2,3,...), when i click paging in `gdvNotification`, it not run. Page is reload but page index is `0`.

When i select other item in `grvHeadline` and reselect first item, then click paging in `gdvNotification`, it run, page index was changed.

I was debug: When the page is load first time: I click to page index in `gdvNotification` then `pageload()` was called with `IsPostBack=True`, but not call to event `gdvNotification_PageIndexChanging` of `gdvNotification`.

Here is my code:

```
protected void gdvNotification_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    logger.Debug("Gridview Headline page index changing .");
    gdvNotification.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    HeadlineSelected(hdfNotificationIdSelected.Value, e.NewPageIndex);
    //gdvNotification.DataBind();
    lbPageIndex.Text = (e.NewPageIndex + 1).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

And

```
private void HeadlineSelected(string notificationIdSelected, int index)
{
    logger.Debug("Head line selected");
    GetDataFromSessionAndCache();
    IList<InformationEntity> infoNotificationList = new List<InformationEntity>();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(notificationIdSelected))
    {
        //Clear
        IList<InformationEntity> data = new List<InformationEntity>()
                                            {
                                                new InformationEntity()
                                                    {
                                                        AuthorName = string.Empty,
                                                        Contents = string.Empty,
                                                        BulletinDateFrom = null,
                                                        BulletinDateTo = null,
                                                        Id = string.Empty,
                                                        Subject = string.Empty,
                                                    }
                                            };
        gdvNotification.DataSource = data;
        gdvNotification.DataBind();
        pnPageIndex.Visible = false;
        btnEditNotification.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        infoNotificationList = MasterDataHelper.GetInformationByHighOrderId(notificationIdSelected);
        logger.Debug("Notification list not null");
        if (infoNotificationList != null)
        {
            if (infoNotificationList.Count == 0)
            {
                pnPageIndex.Visible = false;
                hdfNotificationId.Value = string.Empty;
                btnEditNotification.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (infoNotificationList.Count == 1)
                {
                    fakepanel.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    fakepanel.Visible = false;
                }
                if (base.IsPermission(PERMISSION_INFORMATION_FOLLOWUP))
                {
                    btnEditNotification.Enabled = true;
                }
                pnPageIndex.Visible = true;
                gdvNotification.PageIndex = index;
                hdfNotificationId.Value = infoNotificationList[index].Id;
                gdvNotification.DataSource = infoNotificationList;
                gdvNotification.DataBind();
            }
            logger.Debug("Set value for label total page");
            lblTotalPage.Text = gdvNotification.PageCount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            lbPageIndex.Text = gdvNotification.PageCount == 0
                                   ? gdvNotification.PageCount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                   : (gdvNotification.PageIndex + 1).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            lbTotal.Text = infoNotificationList.Count().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
}
```

Update code in view  *.aspx.

```
<table style="padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 25px; table-layout: fixed" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 49%" class="Top">
            <table class="Master" style="width: 100%; height: 35px; border-spacing: 2px 0px">
                <tr style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                    <td class="BasicValue" style="width: 100%; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFuzzySearch" runat="server" Style="width: 76%; height: 25px; text-align: left;
                                float: left; border-style: double; border-color: Gray;" />
                            <asp:Label ID="label" runat="server" Text="※あいまい検索" Width="20%" Style="text-align: center;
                                vertical-align: middle; margin-top: 5px;" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Button" Style="display: none" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="panelContainer" runat="server"  Width="100%" Height="582px" Style="margin-top: 0px;overflow-y: auto">
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfNotificationIdSelected" runat="server" Value="" />
                        <asp:GridView ID="grvHeadline" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Style="width: 100%"
                            BorderWidth="0px" CellSpacing="2" CellPadding="10" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="false"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="grvHeadline_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="grvHeadline_RowDataBound">
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="BasicColumnTitle" />
                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="RowStyleEven" />
                            <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyleOdd" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="RowStyleHi heallineSelected" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />
                                    <ItemStyle Width="80%" />
                                    <ItemTemplate>

                                        <table style="border-spacing: 0px">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" ImageAlign="Left" Style="display: none" ImageUrl="../img/triangle-on.png" />
                                                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageAlign="Left" Style="display: none" ImageUrl="../img/triangle-off.png" />
                                                <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" Visible='<% #int.Parse(Eval("ThreadQty").ToString()) < 2%>'
                                            ImageAlign="Left" ImageUrl="../img/Doc1.png" />
                                        <asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" Visible='<% #int.Parse(Eval("ThreadQty").ToString())>=2%>'
                                            ImageAlign="Left" ImageUrl="../img/Doc2.png" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label CssClass="bold" Style="resize: none; width: 100%; margin-left: 5px; vertical-align: bottom;  
                                                    text-align: justify" ID="txt1" Text='<%#DevideString(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("Subject")), 35) %>' runat="server">
                                                </asp:Label><br />
                                                <asp:Label  CssClass="bold" Style="resize: none; margin-left: 5px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: justify;"
                                                    ID="txt2" Text='<%#DevideString(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("AuthorName")), 35) %>' runat="server" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfSelectedId" runat="server" Value='<% #Eval("Id")%>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="3%" />
                                    <ItemStyle Width="20%" VerticalAlign="Top" CssClass="position" />
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <table style="border-spacing: 0px; height: 100%;" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="Top Left" style="height: auto;">
                                                    <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" CssClass="Top Left" Visible='<%# ShowImgUpScreen(DateTime.Parse(Eval("BulletinDateFrom").ToString()),Eval("ThreadQty").ToString()) %>'
                                                        ImageAlign="Left" Style="vertical-align: top;" ImageUrl="~/img/Up1.png" />
                                                    <asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" CssClass="Top Left" Visible='<%# ShowImgNewScreen(DateTime.Parse(Eval("BulletinDateFrom").ToString()),Eval("ThreadQty").ToString()) %>'
                                                        ImageAlign="Left" Style="vertical-align: top;" ImageUrl="~/img/New2.png" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" CssClass="Right Bottom" Text='<%#CheckDateTime((DateTime)Eval("BulletinDateFrom"))%>'
                                            Style="float: right; position: absolute; bottom: 3px; right: 3px" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="grvHeadline" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <table class="BasicValue" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: -58px; margin-top: 43.5px">
                <tr style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; margin: 100px 0px 0px 0px;">
                    <td class="BasicValue" style="padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnNewHeadline" class="ButtonSchedule" runat="server" Text="ヘッドラインの新親追加"
                            Height="100%" Style="text-align: center; float: right; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;"
                                Width="165px" OnClick="btnNewHeadlineRegist_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 1%;" class="Center">
                <div class="verticalLine" style="background-color: #C5C5CA; text-align: center; height: 696px;
                    width: 4px; margin-left: 48%">
                </div>
            </td>
        <td style="width: 49%; position: relative" class="Top">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfNotificationId" runat="server" />
                        <asp:GridView ID="gdvNotification" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Style="width: 100%;"
                            BorderWidth="0px" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="0" GridLines="None" PageSize="1"
                            AllowPaging="True" ShowHeader="false" OnPageIndexChanging="gdvNotification_PageIndexChanging">
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="BasicColumnTitle" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="618" ScrollBars="Vertical">
                                            <table style="width: 100%;">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr style="height: 40px">
                                                        <td class="BasicValue" style="vertical-align: bottom;padding-left:2em">
                                                            <div>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblhead" CssClass="bold" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("Subject")%>' Style=" font-weight: bold"></asp:Label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr style="height: 40px">
                                                        <td class=" BasicValue" style="vertical-align: bottom ;padding-left: 2em;">
                                                            <div>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Style=" font-weight: bold" Text='<% #Eval("AuthorName")%>'></asp:Label><asp:Label
                                                                    ID="Label3" runat="server" Style="float: right" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm}",Eval("BulletinDateFrom"))%>'></asp:Label></div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr style="height: 40px">
                                                        <td class="BasicValue" style="vertical-align: bottom">
                                                            <div>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblSection" runat="server" Style="padding-left: 2em;" Text='<%# GetSectionName(Eval("Id").ToString())%>'></asp:Label>
                                                            </div>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr style="height: 497px;">
                                                        <td class="BasicValue" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding-left:2em ">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblContent" runat="server"
                                                                Text='<% #Eval("Contents")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </asp:Panel>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="fakepanel" Height="30px">
                </asp:Panel>
                    <div class="Center" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0cm; font-family: ＭＳ Ｐゴシック">
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnPageIndex" runat="server">
                            <span>Page
                                <asp:Label ID="lbPageIndex" runat="server" /><span>/</span><asp:Label ID="lblTotalPage"
                                    runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                <span>(<asp:Label ID="lbTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>件)</span></span>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
                    <table style="width: 100%;position: absolute; bottom: 0px">
                        <tr style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                            <td class="BasicValue" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; width: 100%; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnEditNotification" CssClass="ButtonSchedule" runat="server" Text="お知らせの編集"
                                Height="85%" Style="float: left; text-align: center; margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px; position: relative; left: 260px"
                                Width="158px" OnClick="btnEditNotification_Click" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateNotification" CssClass="ButtonSchedule" runat="server" Text="このお知らせに追記"
                                Height="85%" Style="float: right; text-align: center; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;"
                                Width="158px" OnClick="btnUpdateNotification_Click" />

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="grvHeadline" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gdvNotification" EventName="PageIndexChanging" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can somebody tell me what's happening?

(p/s: i'm trying to learning English, if you don't understand, please tell me.)

Comment: Is gdvNotification_PageIndexChanging getting called when you click on page index?

Comment: When the page is load first time: when I click on page index, gdvNotification_PageIndexChanging getting  not called. But if I select other item in grvHeadline and reselect First item then click on page index, gdvNotification_PageIndexChanging getting was called.

Comment: You mean when clicked on grvHeadline page index "gdvNotification_PageIndexChanging " is getting called?

Comment: I select one item (ex:item A) in grvHeadline and load data for gdvNotification by A.Id. If gdvNotification  has  paging, I click on  gdvNotification  page index.

Comment: You have "OnPageIndexChanging="gdvNotification_PageIndexChanging" set for your gdvNotification grid right?

Comment: Yes I have. And my problem is: when the page load first time, event gdvNotification_PageIndexChanging not run. When I select other item  in grvHeadline and reselect first item then click page index on gdvNotification, event gdvNotification_PageIndexChanging  was called.

Comment: I guess this is because of Update panel. Try changing the "UpdateMode" property of your UpdatePanel.

Comment: I'm trying to use UpdateMode with "UpdateMode=Condition" or "UpdateMode=Always" but it not run.

Comment: Give a try by removing update panel.

Comment: I think there is something wrong in my codebehide. At home, I created a sample page with two griview and update panel, page index on  gdvNotification is working properly. I will debug again in mycode behide. If you have any idea, please tell me. @ Naveen:  Thanks for your support, have a nice day.:)

Comment: hi all. when I click page index on gdvNotification  (page=2) in screen, page reload and paging not working, But when I run this code "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$gdvNotification','Page$2')" in console of browser, page index on gdvNotification is working properly. Can somebody tell me what is happening?